# Unable to consume kafka messages using spark streaming application

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to create objects by parsing csv file and publish them as json string to kafka queue. I have also written a spark streaming application to consume those messages from the kafka topic.

When i started my spark streaming application and produce the messages through kafka i do not see any messages getting printed. The logs does not make any sense as i am not able to understand anything much to debug. Could someone help me with this.

Spark Streaming application

```
package com.api.streams.consumer;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction2;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Time;

public class SparkConsumer {

    private static SparkConf conf;
    private static JavaSparkContext sc;
    private static JavaStreamingContext ssc;
    private static final Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark-Streaming-Application")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));

        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("test");

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils
                .createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, String.class,
                        StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams,
                        topics);

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction2<JavaPairRDD<String, String>,Time>(){

            /**
             * serial version uuid
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void call(JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd, Time time)
                    throws Exception {

                rdd.foreach(data -> {
                    System.out.println(data._1 + "  " + data._2);
                });
            }

        });
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

Kafka producer

```
package com.kafka.api.utilities;

import com.kafka.api.models.Person;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerUtilities {

    public static org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, Person> getProducer() {
        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,
                "kafka json producer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "localhost:9092");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "com.kafka.api.serdes.JsonSerializer");

        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, Person> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Person>(
                configProperties);
        return producer;
    }

    public ProducerRecord<String, Person> createRecord(Person person) {
        ProducerRecord<String, Person> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Person>(
                "test", person);
        return record;
    }

}

package com.kafka.api.kafkastreaming;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import com.kafka.api.models.Person;
import com.kafka.api.utilities.ConsumerUtilities;
import com.kafka.api.utilities.ProducerUtilities;

public class MainApp {

    private static ProducerUtilities producerutility = new ProducerUtilities();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, Person> producer = ProducerUtilities
                    .getProducer();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Person> listofpersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
                ClassLoader classloader = new MainApp().getClass()
                        .getClassLoader();
                File file = new File(classloader.getResource("MOCK_DATA.csv")
                        .getFile());
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line = " ";
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] persons = line.split(",");
                        Person person = new Person();
                        person.setName(persons[0]);
                        person.setPersonalID(persons[1]);
                        person.setCountry(persons[2]);
                        person.setOccupation(persons[3]);
                        listofpersons.add(person);
                    }

                    for (Person person : listofpersons) {
                        System.out
                                .println("pushing record to the kafka producer");
                        ProducerRecord<String, Person> record = producerutility
                                .createRecord(person);
                        producer.send(record);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        producer.start();

//      Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
//              try {
//                  ConsumerUtilities.printStreamData();
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
//          }
//      });
//
//      consumer.start();

    }

}
```

Log:

> 17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1523.0,
>   whose tasks have all completed, from pool  17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1523 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52)
>   finished in 0.000 s 17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1523
>   finished: foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52, took 0.020257 s 17/10/09
>   03:54:15 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1507546455000
>   ms.0 from job set of time 1507546455000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.028 s for time 1507546455000 ms
>   (execution: 0.022 s) 17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD
>   1522 from persistence list 17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO
>   ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches:  17/10/09 03:54:15 INFO
>   InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1507546453000 ms 17/10/09
>   03:54:15 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1522 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1507546456000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546456000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO JobScheduler:
>   Added jobs for time 1507546456000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   SparkContext: Starting job: foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52 17/10/09
>   03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1524 (foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52) with 1 output partitions 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1524 (foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of
>   final stage: List() 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing
>   parents: List() 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting
>   ResultStage 1524 (KafkaRDD[1524] at createDirectStream at
>   SparkConsumer.java:37), which has no missing parents 17/10/09 03:54:16
>   INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1524 stored as values in memory
>   (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1524_piece0 stored as bytes in memory
>   (estimated size 1764.0 B, free 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1524_piece0 in memory on
>   10.0.2.15:33259 (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1524 from broadcast at
>   DAGScheduler.scala:1006 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler:
>   Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1524 (KafkaRDD[1524] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37) (first 15 tasks are for
>   partitions Vector(0)) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding
>   task set 1524.0 with 1 tasks 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO TaskSetManager:
>   Starting task 0.0 in stage 1524.0 (TID 1524, localhost, executor
>   driver, partition 0, ANY, 4744 bytes) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO Executor:
>   Running task 0.0 in stage 1524.0 (TID 1524) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 50 is the same as ending offset skipping
>   test 0 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage
>   1524.0 (TID 1524). 708 bytes result sent to driver 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1524.0 (TID 1524) in 2
>   ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1) 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1524.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage
>   1524 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) finished in 0.000 s 17/10/09
>   03:54:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1524 finished: foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52, took 0.009639 s 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1507546456000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546456000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO JobScheduler:
>   Total delay: 0.019 s for time 1507546456000 ms (execution: 0.013 s)
>   17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD 1523 from persistence
>   list 17/10/09 03:54:16 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1523 17/10/09
>   03:54:16 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches:  17/10/09
>   03:54:16 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata:
>   1507546454000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for
>   time 1507546457000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO SparkContext: Starting
>   job: foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1507546457000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546457000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Got
>   job 1525 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) with 1 output partitions
>   17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1525
>   (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1525 (KafkaRDD[1525] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37), which has no missing
>   parents 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1525
>   stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 553.1 MB)
>   17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1525_piece0 stored
>   as bytes in memory (estimated size 1764.0 B, free 553.1 MB) 17/10/09
>   03:54:17 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1525_piece0 in memory
>   on 10.0.2.15:33259 (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:17
>   INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1525 from broadcast at
>   DAGScheduler.scala:1006 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO DAGScheduler:
>   Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1525 (KafkaRDD[1525] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37) (first 15 tasks are for
>   partitions Vector(0)) 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding
>   task set 1525.0 with 1 tasks 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO TaskSetManager:
>   Starting task 0.0 in stage 1525.0 (TID 1525, localhost, executor
>   driver, partition 0, ANY, 4744 bytes) 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO Executor:
>   Running task 0.0 in stage 1525.0 (TID 1525) 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 50 is the same as ending offset skipping
>   test 0 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage
>   1525.0 (TID 1525). 665 bytes result sent to driver 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1525.0 (TID 1525) in 2
>   ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1) 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1525.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage
>   1525 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) finished in 0.000 s 17/10/09
>   03:54:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1525 finished: foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52, took 0.007133 s 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1507546457000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546457000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO JobScheduler:
>   Total delay: 0.012 s for time 1507546457000 ms (execution: 0.008 s)
>   17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD 1524 from persistence
>   list 17/10/09 03:54:17 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1524 17/10/09
>   03:54:17 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches:  17/10/09
>   03:54:17 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata:
>   1507546455000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job
>   streaming job 1507546458000 ms.0 from job set of time 1507546458000 ms
>   17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1507546458000
>   ms 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job
>   1526 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) with 1 output partitions
>   17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1526
>   (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1526 (KafkaRDD[1526] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37), which has no missing
>   parents 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1526
>   stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 553.1 MB)
>   17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1526_piece0 stored
>   as bytes in memory (estimated size 1764.0 B, free 553.1 MB) 17/10/09
>   03:54:18 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1526_piece0 in memory
>   on 10.0.2.15:33259 (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:18
>   INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1526 from broadcast at
>   DAGScheduler.scala:1006 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO DAGScheduler:
>   Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1526 (KafkaRDD[1526] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37) (first 15 tasks are for
>   partitions Vector(0)) 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding
>   task set 1526.0 with 1 tasks 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO TaskSetManager:
>   Starting task 0.0 in stage 1526.0 (TID 1526, localhost, executor
>   driver, partition 0, ANY, 4744 bytes) 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO Executor:
>   Running task 0.0 in stage 1526.0 (TID 1526) 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 50 is the same as ending offset skipping
>   test 0 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage
>   1526.0 (TID 1526). 708 bytes result sent to driver 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1526.0 (TID 1526) in 3
>   ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1) 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1526.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage
>   1526 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) finished in 0.000 s 17/10/09
>   03:54:18 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1526 finished: foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52, took 0.011234 s 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1507546458000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546458000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO JobScheduler:
>   Total delay: 0.019 s for time 1507546458000 ms (execution: 0.012 s)
>   17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD 1525 from persistence
>   list 17/10/09 03:54:18 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 1525 17/10/09
>   03:54:18 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches:  17/10/09
>   03:54:18 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata:
>   1507546456000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for
>   time 1507546459000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO SparkContext: Starting
>   job: foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1507546459000 ms.0 from job
>   set of time 1507546459000 ms 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Got
>   job 1527 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) with 1 output partitions
>   17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1527
>   (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1527 (KafkaRDD[1527] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37), which has no missing
>   parents 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1527
>   stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 553.1 MB)
>   17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1527_piece0 stored
>   as bytes in memory (estimated size 1764.0 B, free 553.1 MB) 17/10/09
>   03:54:19 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1524_piece0 on
>   10.0.2.15:33259 in memory (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1527_piece0 in memory
>   on 10.0.2.15:33259 (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:19
>   INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1523_piece0 on
>   10.0.2.15:33259 in memory (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1525_piece0 on
>   10.0.2.15:33259 in memory (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1526_piece0 on
>   10.0.2.15:33259 in memory (size: 1764.0 B, free: 553.1 MB) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1527 from broadcast at
>   DAGScheduler.scala:1006 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO DAGScheduler:
>   Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1527 (KafkaRDD[1527] at
>   createDirectStream at SparkConsumer.java:37) (first 15 tasks are for
>   partitions Vector(0)) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding
>   task set 1527.0 with 1 tasks 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO TaskSetManager:
>   Starting task 0.0 in stage 1527.0 (TID 1527, localhost, executor
>   driver, partition 0, ANY, 4744 bytes) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO Executor:
>   Running task 0.0 in stage 1527.0 (TID 1527) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 50 is the same as ending offset skipping
>   test 0 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage
>   1527.0 (TID 1527). 665 bytes result sent to driver 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1527.0 (TID 1527) in 1
>   ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1) 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO
>   TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1527.0, whose tasks have all
>   completed, from pool  17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage
>   1527 (foreach at SparkConsumer.java:52) finished in 0.001 s 17/10/09
>   03:54:19 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1527 finished: foreach at
>   SparkConsumer.java:52, took 0.011742 s 17/10/09 03:54:19 INFO

Comment: Can you confirm whether data is in kafka topic or not?
and you are producing data in <String,Person> fashion and consuming the same in <String, String>

Comment: @AkashSethi  yes the topic has data i am able to consume it from another kafka stream consumer without any issues.

Comment: Do you first produce and then start streaming job? Or vice verse?

Comment: The spark streaming application is executed as a daemon. The producer is then started to produce the messages @Natalia